# Преобразование одного массива в другой в C# без LINQ

Tags: linq, c#

Есть один массив.

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5 };
```

Нужно получить из этого массива новый, где каждый элемент будет квадратом исходного.

```
int[] squares = { 1, 9, 25};
```

Сейчас я осуществляю преобразование, используя LINQ.

```
int[] squares = numbers.Select(n => n*n).ToArray();
```

В целом это простой, понятный и удобный метод. Но есть сомнения в эффективности такого подхода для простых преобразований (например, int в float). Есть ли сравнимый метод без LINQ для таких случаев?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для преобразования массивов есть специальный метод [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/exc45z53.aspx):

```
int[] squares = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, n => n*n);
```

Можно замерить время выполнения для варианта с LINQ и без LINQ на больших массивах и посмотреть, есть ли выигрыш и насколько он существенен.

Answer (score 1):

Проще и быстрее всего так

```
var squares = new int[numbers.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < squares.Length; i++)
{
  var current_num = numbers[i];
  squares[i] = current * current;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не согласен c gluk. Если заводить список, то уж лучше

```
var squares = new List<int>(numbers.Length);
```

т.к. и размер известен, и, главное, `squares.ToArray()` вернёт не `object[]`, а `int[]`.

Но зачем заводить список?? Можно сразу завести массив `int[]` с размером `numbers.Length` и заполнять его.

Comment: Да, так лучше.

Answer (score -1):

Можно использовать ArrayList.

```
 using System.Collections;

 int[] numbers = { 1, 3, 5 };
 ArrayList squares = new ArrayList();
 foreach(int n in numbers)
 {
    squares.Add(n*n);
 }
```

Хотя это не совсем массив в чистом виде, но можно преобразовать в object[]

```
squares.ToArray()
```

Comment: Метод безусловно работает, но число строк кода увеличилось. Не думаю, что это удачная замена LINQ.